# What happens when I turn my ethernet off? What steps does the OS perform once I turn the ethernet OFF?

Tags: networking, systemd, embedded, ethernet

I want to know what actually happens once I turn my ethernet OFF.
What does the OS do on a network layer?
Does it flush the routing table or anything like that.

Comment: How do you mean "_I turn my ethernet off_"? Is this a software switch on the client, or unplugging the cable, or powering off an intermediate switch, or ...?

Comment: This is could be either right unplugging it and shutting it down via software

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux kernel describes every Ethernet adapter(physical device or virtual) by `struct net_device` ([struct net_device](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.19/networking/kapi.html#c.net_device)). Every `struct net_device` has a set of `struct net_device_ops` which should be implemented by device driver. The most important of them:

- `ndo_open()`. Called when you set Ethernet adapter to ON (`ip link set up dev <eth_dev>`).
- `ndo_start_xmit()`. Called when you start transmit data through the interface.
- `ndo_stop()`. Called when you set Ethernet adapter to OFF(`ip link set down dev <eth_dev>`).

So, what's really does when device is going DOWN?

There are set of routines which implemented in most drivers:

- stop all queues related to specific device.
- clear ARP table entries related to specific device.
- mark interface status as `DOWN` (`ip link show dev <eth_dev>`).
- device specific features: clear some structs, buffers, move Ethernet controllers chip to sleep...